# Adding values in Windows Form?

Tags: c#

I have an app I am making and the issue is when I press the Plus button it will add $100 when I press it again nothing happens and I am unsure of a fix, here is the code I'm using.

```
GlobalVariables.LukasGrahamTotal = +100; 
lblLukas.Text = Convert.ToString(GlobalVariables.LukasGrahamTotal);
```

Comment: Can you show a complete code sample? How do you handle the plus button click event?

Comment: Since you wrote **value = +100** and not **value =+ 100** the value is always filled with **+100**

Comment: Thank You @Radinator , should of double checked my code. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this is just a typo but the short form of increment by some value operator is not =+ but it is +=.

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
GlobalVariables.LukasGrahamTotal += 100;
lblLukas.Text = Convert.ToString(GlobalVariables.LukasGrahamTotal);
```

To increment by 100 you should use `+=` and not `=+`.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
GlobalVariables.LukasGrahamTotal += 100;
```